Execute all slurm jobs as single user
Is it possible in slurm to run all jobs on computation nodes using single specific user, in the same time log to the accounting db the user who submitted the job ( using job_submit lua plugin or spank or something similar?). So if user 1000 (on a login node) submitted job, we would like to log to the accounting db that this job is submitted by user 1000, but the job process on the computation node runs with user 2000.
Tried to change job_desc.user_id in "slurm_job_submit()" in job_submit lua plugin but it is read only.
